# Message Queue Timelimit warning

Tags: message-queue, orocommerce

I'm currently trying to configure my Oro Community Shop - running on Docker (WSL2 Backend).
While i configured some products and the Web Catalogue, I noticed that some of it is not showing up at the FrontEnd. I tried to run the message consumer on different options like:

symfony run -d php bin/console oro:message-queue:consume --time-limit=+1200 seconds --memory-limit=556MB -v --env=dev

But no matter what this error/warning occurs.

[Application] May 20 08:40:34 |DEBUG  | CONSUM Switch to a queue oro.seconds
[Application] May 20 08:40:34 |DEBUG  | CONSUM Execution interrupted as limit time has passed. now: "2022-05-20T08:40:34+0200", time-limit: "2022-05-20T08:40:34+0600" extension="Oro\Component\MessageQueue\Consumption\Extension\LimitConsumptionTimeExtension"
[Application] May 20 08:40:34 |DEBUG  | DOCTRI SELECT updated_at FROM oro_message_queue_state WHERE id = :id extension="Oro\Bundle\MessageQueueBundle\Consumption\Extension\ResettableExtensionWrapper" id="cache" memory_usage="101.33 MB"
[Application] May 20 08:40:34 |INFO   | CONSUM Update the consumer state time. memory_usage="101.36 MB"
[Application] May 20 08:40:34 |DEBUG  | DOCTRI UPDATE oro_message_queue_state SET updated_at = :updatedAt WHERE id = :id AND updated_at < :dateWithGap dateWithGap="2022-05-20T06:35:34+00:00" id="consumers" updatedAt="2022-05-20T06:40:34+00:00"
[Application] May 20 08:40:34 |DEBUG  | CONSUM Make sure the queue "oro.seconds" exists on a broker side. memory_usage="102.08 MB"

**[Application] May 20 08:40:34 |WARNING| CONSUM Consuming interrupted, reason: The limit time has passed. memory_usage="102.43 MB"**

Did i forgot/failed to configure something?
It would be great if someone with more experience could help me handle this problem.

Thanks Alex

Answer (score 0):

If it's a local environment, you can omit the time-limit option and restart the process manually when it stops.

In the production environment, it is required to run the message consumer using a supervisor that will automatically restart the consumer when needed. For more details, see https://doc.oroinc.com/backend/mq/supervisord/#supervisord and https://doc.oroinc.com/backend/mq/.